# Why did Jesus forbid the disciples to take a change of clothes on their mission journey in Luke 9:3?

Tags: luke

Luke 9 New Living Translation

> 1 One day Jesus called together his twelve disciples and gave them power and authority to cast out all demons and to heal all diseases. 2Then he sent them out to tell everyone about the Kingdom of God and to heal the sick. 3“Take nothing for your **journey**,” he instructed them. “Don’t take a walking stick, a traveler’s bag, food, money, or even a **change of clothes**. 4Wherever you go, stay in the same house until you leave town. 5And if a town refuses to welcome you, shake its dust from your feet as you leave to show that you have abandoned those people to their fate.”
> 6So they began their **circuit** of the villages, preaching the Good News and healing the sick.

Sounds like a multi-days journey of walking. For cleanliness reason, shouldn't they have taken a change of clothes?

Comment: They would be staying in the homes of hospitable hosts who would let them use the washer and dryer or perhaps donate a garment for them to wear

Comment: I am mystified by this rather obvious question.  The text says what it says!  The travelling missionaries were to depend on the hearers of the gospel for all things as V4 makes clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point was to rely completely on God rather than their own provision - not that they didn't need a change of clothes, or food, or money, or a walking stick. God will make sure that they get the change of clothes, walking stick, food, or money that they need.

This is reminiscent of:

Matt 6.28-34

> And why are you anxious about clothing? Observe the lilies of the
> field, how they grow: they do not toil or spin, but I say to you that
> not even Solomon in all his glory was dressed like one of these.
>
> But
> if God dresses the grass of the field in this way, although it is here
> today and tomorrow is thrown into the oven, will he not do so much
> more for you, you of little faith?
>
> Therefore do not be anxious,
> saying, ‘What will we eat?’ or ‘What will we drink?’ or ‘What will we
> wear?,’ for the pagans seek after all these things.
>
> For your heavenly
> Father knows that you need all these things.
>
> But seek first his
> kingdom and righteousness, and all these things will be added to you.
>
> Therefore do not be anxious for tomorrow, because tomorrow will be
> anxious for itself. Each day has enough trouble of its own.